# If a String is found in cell A1, Replace in B1 cell python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame as below, here I when I find `"Log file validation"` I need to make its corresponding `SITT` column as `"YES"` and if `"Sequence Validation"` then `"NO"` and it varies for each and every row. I am looping through the contents in `"Checklist"` column and how do I alter the corresponding value in `SITT` column.

```
                                            Checklist SITT
0                                 Log file validation  NaN
1                                 Sequence Validation  NaN
2                       Recreating failed constraints  NaN
3                      Synonyms and grants Validation  NaN
4       Creating Table structures for excluded tables  NaN
```

I tried below different method and more different ways, nothing seems to give me expected result.

```
sheet_read.loc[(sheet_read['Checklist'] == 'Log file validation') & (sheet_read['SITT'] == 'NaN'), 'SITW'] = 'Mismatch'
```

Any help on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['SITT'] = df['SITT'].astype(str)
for i, e in enumerate(df['Checklist']):
    if e=='Log file validation':
        df.at[i,'SITT']='yes'
    if e=='Sequence Validation':
        df.at[i,'SITT']='no'
df['SITT'] = df['SITT'].replace('nan', np.nan)
```

Comment: I am getting the following error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'YES'`

Comment: I have made the values of SITT manually to be empty by using the following command `NaN=np.nan
sheet_read["SITT"]=NaN` Can that be the reason, if so how do I overcome it?

Comment: @sabarishjackson Updated my answer. Converted np.nan to "nan" and after the job is done, back to np.nan